# Convert strings to links

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've created a component in NextJS that converts a string in a text into a link of own choosing.

```
export const StringToLink = ({
  href,
  initialText,
  stringToReplace,
  useAnchorTag = false,
}: {
  initialText: string;
  stringToReplace: string;
  useAnchorTag?: boolean;
  href: string;
}) => {
  const Tag = useAnchorTag ? 'a' : Link;

  return initialText.split(stringToReplace).map((text, index, array) => (
    <>
      {text} {index < array.length - 1 && <Tag href={href}>{stringToReplace}</Tag>}
    </>
  ));
};
```

It is used like this

```
              <StringToLink
                initialText="Mail this to me and checkout my website"
                stringToReplace="this"
                href="mailto:my@mail.com"
                useAnchorTag
              />
```

However, it could happen that I want to link two strings to links. With my example initialText above, **this** is an email-link, and **website** would be linked to href="https://www.mywebsite.com"

I guess that I should do some looping in my StringToLink-component. I want it to allow either one string or an array of strings to change to links (or link). So stringsToReplace: string | string[]; and href: string | string[].

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the prop interface to take a mapping object instead of the two individual props.

Something like

```js
replaceMap={{ this: 'mailto:my@email.com', website: 'https://www.mywebsite.com' }}
```

Here's a rough pass at something using that prop interface, just as a proof of concept:

```js
const StringToLink = ({
  initialText,
  replaceMap,
  useAnchorTag = false,
}) => {
  return initialText.split(' ').map((text, i, array) => {
    const space = i == array.length - 1 ? '' : ' ';
    if (!!replaceMap[text]) {
      return (
          <span><a href={replaceMap[text]}>{text}</a>{space}</span>
      );
    } else {
      return `${text}${space}`;
    }
  });
}

const App = () => {
  return (
  <StringToLink
      initialText="Mail this to me and checkout my website"
      replaceMap={{ this: 'mailto:my@email.com', website: 'https://www.mywebsite.com' }}
      useAnchorTag
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Fantastic! This was way cleaner. The initialText comes from my backend and I went insane trying to figure this out. Thank you very much Brian!